# javascript cannot read property '0' of undefined in graphql query

Tags: javascript, undefined, graphql

I'm failing to set a value in this constant:

```
const targetedMessageTemplate = { 
    "query": createTargetedMessage(input: {
         conversationId: '',
         targetUserId: '',
         targetDialogId: '',
         annotations: [{
             genericAnnotation: {
                 title: '',
                 text: ''
             }
         }]
    }) 
};
```

When calling this:

```
var test= targetedMessageTemplate;

test.annotations[0].title = 'Test title';
```

Returns:

```
TypeError: cannot read '0' of undefined.
```

Setting the value of the conversationId variable works fine, however accessing the annotations array seems to be an issue.

Any hint appreciated on what I'm missing is highly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Can you share related section of your GraphiQL response?

Answer (score 1):

**genericAnnotation** object key is not written.

```
test.annotations[0].genericAnnotation.title = 'Test title';
```

But error is different. Are you sure **annotations** isn't an empty array?

Comment: Yes sorry I also tried `test.annotations[0].genericAnnotation.title = 'Test title';` which is the correct call, but the error as you said is before accessing genericAnnotation. I'm not sure how the array could be empty since it's declared in the constant ?

Comment: Why you don't look the response, or log **test.annotions**? Because **test.annotations** is exist, but it isn't contain any value. I was try an example like this, I could get some values. I think the error is related to **annotations** variable.